# calculate cubic from 2 gradients and 2 points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives, polynomials

I have a question that is supposed to be solved using differentiation, wherein I have to find a cubic function ***f(x)*** where the gradient at ***(5,20)*** is *zero* and the gradient at ***(8,22)*** is *two*.

[image of co-ordinates on the graph for cubic function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys4GO.png)

I know that I need to use 4 linear simultaneous equations with 4 variables ***(a,b,c,d)***, however, I'm not quite sure how to go about doing so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, start with a linear function that passes through your two points.  Add an appropriate multiple of $(x-5)(x-8)^2$ to get the slope you want at $x=5$ and an appropriate multiple of $(x-8)(x-5)^2$ to get the right slope at $x=8$.